# Where can I find a list of all window class names?

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to use the function "findwindowex" (windows API)
I wanted to know what appropriate values ​​for the parameter "ClassName".
Are the tables that are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) show the possible values​​?
If not - where can I find details of all types "ClassName"?
(Am I understood? I do not know good English.)

Comment: Do you think your title is good for your problem? Be spesific..

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide details of your underlying problem. What is your ultimate goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, those are the names of some classes registered by the system. A great many Windows applications will be built with classes registered by those applications.

If you wish to find the name of the window class used by a particular window, use [`GetClassName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: But GetClassName returns numbers. Are the numbers are class name?

Comment: @Baruch GetClassName returns the name. Please read the documentatation more carefully.

Comment: So I do not understand.
MSDN says "Return Value
Type: int "
Does that mean the return value is an integer?

Comment: You need to read the whole description: `If the function succeeds, the return value is the number of characters copied to the buffer`

Comment: @Baruch The name is returned in the `lpClassName` parameter which is an `out` parameter.

Comment: I see I do not understand. Can anyone write a simple code that displays the use of "classname"?
baruchiro@gmail.com
Thank you!

Comment: it's like every other function that works this way. Find a sample use of GetWindowText and copy the method. Don't ask anyone to email you help, we don't do that here.

Comment: So someone maybe can help me write a a question?
I want to know use the function FindWindowEx, and because there are lots of forum rules, I can not ask that every time I ask I have a mistake.

Comment: If you do not know how to call GetClassName then I think your first step is to learn how to code in C.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a tool like SPY.EXE that's included somewhere as part of the win32 SDK. It shows the classname of the window currently under your cursor.

Comment: What is SPY.EXE? Where do I find it?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Spy++ I believe when you hover over the window after clicking the Find button it shows all the information about the window.